# Strange effect when importing DAE model retrieved on the web

Tags: sdformat, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to enlarge my models database by retrieving models from the 3D warehouse.

As a reference I'm following [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model) tutorial. And the procedure I follow to generate a COLLADA model is the [following](https://youtu.be/PDIaUWenu0Q).

To check the outcome of the procedure, I open the .dae model with Meshlab. And this is what I get!

[image: image description]

So, I'm pretty happy with the result!!!

Next, I create a gazebo model in the following steps:

- go to `~/gazebo/models` folder
- create a folder to store the necessary files (e.g. `./armchair`)
- create `model.config` and `model.sdf` files
- copy the `model.dae` file in the `./armchair/meshes` folder
- copy the texture images (if any) in the `./armchair/materials/textures/` folder

where the `model.config` file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<model>
  <name>armchair</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf version="1.5">model.sdf</sdf>

  <author>
    <name>Federico Nardi</name>
    <email>fnardi@dis.uniroma1.it</email>
  </author>

  <description>
  Armchair
  </description>
</model>
```

and the  `model.sdf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="armchair">
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://armchair/meshes/model.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://armchair/meshes/model.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

When I insert the model in gazebo, this is the picture:

[image: image description]

As you can see the textures are correctly loaded, but the edges of the model are marked in white!

Can someone please explain me what's happening?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: @sloretz, here is the `model.dae`:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J5fCXaAUsOCd_KaECSbFKw12EhtSEnID

https://drive.google.com/a/dis.uniroma1.it/file/d/1amriasNXdOZe8f-K9m1vVqMEiBtLCQrf/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/a/dis.uniroma1.it/file/d/1TTqAamutCRL5gWq0O1hKtXR-nLJHa6uM/view?usp=sharing

---

EDIT 2: @nkoenig, I'm using Gazebo 7.0.0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17987/strange-effect-when-importing-dae-model-retrieved-on-the-web/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-12-01**:
Mind posting the collada model?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2017-12-01**:
Can you also say what version of Gazebo you are using?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-12-01**:
Looks like the same weird wireframe effect mentioned on this question: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16802/gazebo-chair-shines-through-the-table-in-the-simulation/

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-12-01**:
Thanks, mind attaching the files `Large_BF_213_1.jpg` and `imitation_gold_leaf_pack_432_300x300_1.jpg` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like blender shows the lines in `Object Mode` too:
[image: image description]

In `model.dae` I see a tag called `<lines>` beginning on line 229. After deleting this block I no longer see the lines in gazebo 7.8.1.

```
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <!-- ... -->
  <library_geometries>
    <geometry id="Mesh14_Group5_Group_15_1_Component1_Model-mesh" name="Mesh14 Group5 Group_15_1 Component1 Model">
      <mesh>
        <!-- ...delete the block below -->
        <lines count="2444">
          <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Mesh14_Group5_Group_15_1_Component1_Model-mesh-vertices" offset="0"/>
          <!-- lots of numbers here -->
        </lines>
        <!-- delete the block above... -->
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </library_geometries>
</COLLADA>
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2